# Total orbital angular momentum in a filled p subshell

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electronic-configuration

From "Physical Chemistry", P. Atkins, J. De Paula, 9th edition, page 358

> "A closed shell has zero orbital angular momentum because all the
> individual orbital angular momenta sum to zero. Therefore, when
> working out term symbols, we need consider only the electrons of the
> unfilled shell."

So, a configuration like $[\text{He}]1s^2$ or $[\text{He}]1s^2 2p^6 $ should have $L = 0$, right? The first presents $L = 0$ for sure, since $l = 0$ for $s$ orbitals and applying the Clebsch-Gordan series we obtain $0$. Doing the same for the second configuration, on the other hand, I obtain values other than $0$.
Could someone explain to me better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of looking at this is to consider that if $L = 1$ (for example), then there must be a state with $M_L = -1$ (because $M_L$ ranges from $-L$ to $L$ in integer steps).

However, $M_L$ is not obtained by a Clebsch–Gordan series: instead, it's just a simple addition of the individual $m_l$'s of each electron. That is:

$$M_L = m_{l,1} + m_{l,2} + m_{l,3} + m_{l,4} + m_{l,5} + m_{l,6}$$

and for a p subshell, the allowed values of $m_l$ are $-1$, $0$, $+1$ (there are two of each). So $M_L$ for a full p subshell must be $0$, and it's then a contradiction to have $L \neq 0$ as that would imply that $M_L$ can have a nonzero value.

This is basically a manifestation of the Pauli exclusion principle, because it is precisely that which forces the sum of $m_l$'s to be zero. If you read around in Atkins, it will mention how certain term symbols are forbidden due to the Pauli exclusion principle. This is a similar case.